# How to re-format a .txt list in Applescript

Tags: macos, text, applescript

I have a file (list.txt) with a list that contains thousands of lines that look like this:

```
carpet-redandblue
shelf-brown
metaldesk-none
```

Is there a script I can use to remove everything after the "-", including the "-" as well?

This is what I have so far:

```
set theFile to "/Users/home/Desktop/list.txt"
if theFile contains "-" then
    set eol to "-"
else
    set eol to "-"
end if
```

But doesn't seem to be working.
Do I have to define an output file with a filename and path?

Comment: An output file is optional. You could assign the results to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need, at least as I understand it. The script reads the text file into a variable. It then breaks the text into paragraphs (or lines) and splits each line at the first dash. It then converts each line back into paragraphs of a text. Finally, it writes the resulting text to a text file. If you prefer to use the resulting text in some other way, it is stored in the `prunedText` variable.

```
use scripting additions

(*
set rawText to "carpet-redandblue
shelf-brown
metaldesk-none"
*)
set rawText to read file ((path to desktop as text) & "list.txt")

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"
set paraText to paragraphs of rawText
--> {"carpet-redandblue", "shelf-brown", "metaldesk-none"}

set wordPara to {}
repeat with eachLine in paraText
    set end of wordPara to first text item of eachLine
end repeat
--> {"carpet", "shelf", "metaldesk"}

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set prunedText to wordPara as text
(*
 "carpet
shelf
metaldesk"
*)

-- optionally
tell application "Finder"
    set nl to ((path to desktop as text) & "newList.txt") as «class furl»
end tell

close access (open for access nl)
write prunedText to nl as text
```

Comment: It runs for a bit, then I get the following error error `"Can’t get text item 1 of \"\"." number -1728 from text item 1 of ""`

Comment: Looks like not every line has a dash. The -1728 error means that condition doesn't exist for at least one line (e.g. get item 3 from {1, 2}. You should try and see how many lines don't have a dash and consider how best to handle them.

Comment: Basically, what the script does after reading the file and breaking it into lines is go line by line and find the text before the first dash (i.e. `first text item`). It then disposes of everything after that in the line. When it hits a line without a dash, it doesn't know what to do so it errors out.

Comment: Ah, Gothca. I used one of my lists that I know has all dashes, then it worked.

Comment: There are a couple of ways that you could address such lines, e.g. put the 'set end of paraText' inside an `if…then` asking if the line contains a dash, or inside a `try` statement which would ignore the line if it failed.

Answer (score 0):

This in my opinion is the easiest solution.

1. Open **Terminal.app**
2. Go to **Finder** and while holding the **⌘** key, drag and drop the folder containing your "list.txt" file directly into a Terminal window.  This will change your current working directory in Terminal to the folder containing your "list.txt" file.
3. Then paste this following code into that Terminal window and press the Return key...

`grep -E -o "^\w*" list.txt > new_list.txt`

*This will create a new file called "new_list.txt" with the hyphens and everything after them removed from each line of your original list.txt*

Comment: Once you have a terminal open, there are lots of options, including `grep -o "^[^-]*" list.txt > new_list.txt` or `awk -F - "{print \$1}" list.txt > new_list.txt`.

Comment: One thing though, not all command utilities support Unicode, so if your file has characters above standard ASCII, you might need to experiment to find a utility that does work.

Comment: When I run this, I get a blank line added to the output after each result line. However, the awk command (in above comment) works well.